# Typescript String literal typing

Tags: typescript, typing

I have this Typescript type

```
export type TCard = {
    col: number;
    id: number;
    hiddenImgPath: "/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg";
    imgPath: "/assets/img/cards";
    onClickCard: Function;
    row: number;
    visible: boolean;
};
```

prop 'hiddenImgPath' will allways have the value "/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg". prop 'imgPath' will always *start* with "/assets/img/cards" but wil have a suffix (as in '/assets/img/cards/card01.jpg'). Then I create an object that is typed as TCard (elsewhere, not inline):

```
({
            col: i % nrOfColumns,
            id: i,
            hiddenImgPath: "/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg",
            imgPath: `${imgPath}/fileName`,
            onClickCard: onClickCard,
            row: Math.floor(i / nrOfColumns),
            visible: true
        })
```

But I get an error:

```
Types of property 'hiddenImgPath' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg"'.
```

Makes sense so I change the type of 'hiddemImgPath' to

```
hiddenImgPath: "/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg" as string;
```

But then I get an error

```
';' expected.  TS1005

    2 |         col: number;
    3 |         id: number;
  > 4 |         hiddenImgPath: "/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg" as string;
      |                                                          ^
    5 |         imgPath: "/assets/img/cards";
    6 |         onClickCard: Function;
    7 |         row: number;
```

Why do I have to add a semicolon there? And why do I have to add / assign the literally typed property 'hiddenImgPath' in the first place when creating the object of type TCard? hiddenImgPath will never have another value than assigned in the type?
But if I leave 'hiddenImgPath' out when creating the object of type TCard I get:

```
Property 'hiddenImgPath' is missing in type '{ col: number; id: number; imgPath: string; onClickCard: (card: {}) => void; row: number; visible: boolean; }' but required 
in type 'TCard'.'
```

I'm out of ideas. Is what I'm trying to do here going against typescript?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `hiddenImgPath` and `imgPath` in your question. The object literal shown doesn't raise an error on `hiddenImgPath`, just on `imgPath`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I have to add a semicolon there?

You don't, but `"/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg" as string` is invalid syntax for a type declaration. You can't use `as` *within* a type annotation; it's for type assertions on *values*.

The `hiddenImgPath` in that object literal is just fine. But `imgPath` can't be defined with a string literal type if the values will only be *prefixed* by that string; you need to use `string` for the type:

```
export type TCard = {
    col: number;
    id: number;
    hiddenImgPath: "/assets/img/cards/hiddenImg.jpg";
    imgPath: string;           // <===========
    onClickCard: Function;
    row: number;
    visible: boolean;
};
```

If you do that, your object literal is just fine. Here it is on the playground with some fixed values in place of your variables: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBhAhlAJnAXjgG8AoOCuAYwgBsAuOAOwFcBbAI2CgG5zKAlrkatO3PpTgALIbmBMAkmwDmABSwwpjAEQB6LAGcDwGAd0CVuqjlxmZuOYpUA6AFZhl2iYJXrNjAxgoASZlbwoIJgxaASoAa2w8RgAxFiYqGAFI8LgoCAB3EXYuXn4KADcBAwEOWmBGDgg6YCwmPgBfPlIaJkC4CA5XRkwbQhIy6jpGABYAJgAaCaEZhYn7RyU1DS04PUNjU3NLazw7WXlNtw9tRckLLf84AAMDCDZgPyldADMBOoA5LDvJ63SiRaKxBI2RgACgAlIQAHwkODtUEUPKFOBzdFwSrVWr1BBQFjAUidIA)

> And why do I have to add / assign the literally typed property 'hiddenImgPath' in the first place when creating the object of type TCard? hiddenImgPath will never have another value than assigned in the type?

Because TypeScript's work happens at *compile-time*, not runtime. It won't automatically fill in properties for you, not even when they have only one valid fixed value. If you want that done once in a central place, you probably want `class` rather than just `type`.

Comment: I really wish I could find the answer I read once which talked about TypeScript having "type contexts" and "value contexts." It might be helpful for the OP. If anyone happens to have a link to the answer I'm thinking of...

Comment: ok, thanks for the answers. I just abstain from using literal string values here.

Comment: @Marc - That probably makes sense for this type, yeah. :-) Happy coding!